# Parsing a JSON result and creating a custom object from it

Tags: javascript, json

**UPDATE**

> All the solutions in this post answer my question, but I can mark only one as excepted answer...

I have this JSON result:

```
[
   { 
      "unsorted1":[7,7,10,3,3]
   },
   {
      "unsorted2":[8,9,3,10,6]
   }
]
```

I would like to make an array in JavaScript that has each the "unsorted1" and "unsorted2" as keys, the [7,7,10,3,3] and [8,9,3,10,6] must remain in JSON format. An object like That unsorted1: [7,7,10,3,3] and unsorted2: [8,9,3,10,6]

This is what I get in the browser using the `console.log(JSON.parse(returnVar));` the `returnVar` parameter holds my JSON result from above.

[image]

I read a lot and tried a lot, but nothing comes close to what I want. Somehow I can't get it done.

I tried modifying this code with no success

```
var resultObj = {};
for (var key in returnVar) {
    if (returnVar.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var val = returnVar[key];
        console.log("val: " + val);
        var keyName = Object.keys(val);
        console.log("key Name: " + keyName);
        for (var keykey in val) {
            if (val.hasOwnProperty(keykey)) {
                var valval = val[keykey]
                resultObj[keyName] = JSON.stringify(valval);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
//if the Json result is an object - this is how you parse it

var objJson = [{
  "unsorted1": [7, 7, 10, 3, 3]
}, {
  "unsorted2": [8, 9, 3, 10, 6]
}];

function parse() {
  if (Array.isArray(objJson) === true) {
    objJson.map(function(i) {
      //alert(JSON.stringify(i));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(i));
    });
  };
}
parse();

//if your json result is a string - this is how you do it
var strJson = "[{\"unsorted1\": [7, 7, 10, 3, 3]}, {\"unsorted2\": [8, 9, 3, 10, 6]}]"; //dont worry about the escaped quotes here - this is a string that is represented here.. but it will work if your JSON result is a string.

function parseString() {
  var objJson = JSON.parse(strJson);
  if (Array.isArray(objJson) === true) {
    objJson.map(function(i) {
      //alert(JSON.stringify(i));
      console.log(JSON.stringify(i));
    });
  };
}
parseString();
```

Comment: My results doesn't have the backslash before and after the unsorted1 and unsorted2. I get this JSON result as stated at the beginning of the post from a c++ code.

Comment: Is there a way not to use the `JSON.parse()` function for a json result is a string?

Comment: What do you mean? Why wouldn't you use JSON.parse() - I mean what is restraining you from using it?

Comment: I have a google portable native client module (PNaCl) that creates the JSON string output, I actually wouldn't want to do the job twice for very big JSON arrays. My normal output will have between 1000000 and 2000000 numbers, if I parse them all and then encode some of them back to JSON in JavaScript, then I loose the advantage of using the PNaCl module for this task.

Comment: @TalG Am sorry, am not familiar with PNaCl or its purpose, nevertheless I do not understand what you mean by `wouldn't want to do the job twice`, if you were to parse the array for specific numbers and encode them then assemble them back to a JSON object, I am not sure how efficiently you can do it without the parse functionality.

Comment: I think I'll have to change my c++ code for the module to send an object back and not the string representation of it. i'll do it  as soon as i'll figure out how it can be done :), thaks for your help! :)

Comment: all the solutions in this post answer my question, however I have changed my PNaCl module (C++ code) to do it, so the JavaScript code is merely an interface between my PNaCl module and my PHP code on the server side.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this code:

```
var response = [
  { 
    "unsorted1":[7,7,10,3,3]
  },
  {
    "unsorted2":[8,9,3,10,6]
  }
];

var customObject = response.reduce(function(result, item) {
  var keys = Object.keys(item);

  if(keys.length) {
    result[keys[0]] = item[keys];
  }

  return result;
}, {});
```

Comment: Your code did exactly what i wanted when i changed the line `result[keys[0]] = item[keys];`  to `result[keys[0]] = JSON.stringify(item[keys]);`

Answer (score 1):

```js
var a = [
    {
        "unsorted1": [7, 7, 10, 3, 3]
    },
    {
        "unsorted2": [8, 9, 3, 10, 6]
    }
]

var b = {}

a.forEach(function(x) {
    Object.keys(x).forEach(function(y) {
        b[y] = JSON.stringify(x[y])
    })
})

console.log(b);
```

Comment: This one was also perfect. Is there a way to do this without using the `JSON.parse(a);` first. The thing is that the JSON array is being sent from my c++ code as a string. Do i have to change my c++ code in order to send it as an array and not as a string?

Comment: @TalG : I have updated my answer based on your comment here. The first version is if the given object is `JsonObject` the next version is if your result is a `string`. Also you need update your question with relevant details as to how you obtain that resultant - you say `C++` what exactly do you mean? is this server side code ? how is your so called `C++` passing this resultant object or how are you calling it from your client